# generating class diagram from existing classes in eclipse IDE

Tags: android, class-diagram

I have created an android application using eclipse IDE, and I want to generate the class diagram for my classes, I've tried to install Objectaid on Eclipse Kepler but I'm having errors. so is there any other plugin for eclipse to generate class diagramme?!

my .log when installing Objectaid

```
 !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse 4 0 2014-05-04 19:15:37.468
 !MESSAGE The bundle manifest could not be read: C:\android-sdk-windows\adt-bundlewindows-x86-20130917\eclipse\plugins\com.objectaid.uml_1.1.5.jar

 !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 4 2014-05-04 19:15:37.468
 !MESSAGE An error occurred while installing the items
  !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 0 2014-05-04 19:15:37.468
  !MESSAGE session context was:(profile=profile,  phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null -->  [R]com.objectaid.uml 1.1.5, action=).
 !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse 4 0 2014-05-04 19:15:37.468
 !MESSAGE Failed to prepare partial IU: [R]com.objectaid.uml 1.1.5.
```

Comment: What errors? Objectaid worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objectaid works for me

info
http://blog.nelsondev.net/?p=93

install it from
http://www.objectaid.com/

Comment: I've updated my post with the error that I'm getting